# My Bootstrap navbar is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using Bootstrap to build my website. For large screens I want to display the navigation bar with buttons. However, when it gets to the medium and below sized screens, I would like it to collapse, just that little menu button present. I have this code so far. The menu icon appears like it's supposed to. It just doesn't do anything when I click on the menu icon. Nothing comes up.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-9">
            <span class="sr-only pull-right">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="index.html">Home</a></button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="description.html">Description</a></button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="location.html">Location</a></button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="availability.html">Availability</a></button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" style="margin-right:0px;"><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></button></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

The code is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/nih5/9D4qj/

Comment: You might want to post this in a jsfiddle.

Comment: You're right @SurrealDreams. It would be useful. I've made one available here. http://jsfiddle.net/nih5/9D4qj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution According to your jsfiddle code.*

Please use this code

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-9" >
```

instead of

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse visible-lg">
```

In css file add the class

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in { display: block !important; }
```

Hope this one help you

### [please check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aFh2D/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the navbar button using `data-target` attribute. For example, I set the id as `target_id`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target_id">
            <span class="sr-only pull-right">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="target_id" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="index.html">Home</a></button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="description.html">Description</a></button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="location.html">Location</a></button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="availability.html">Availability</a></button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" style="margin-right:0px;"><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></button></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It shows up when I click the menu icon, however, disappears as soon as I click it.

Comment: Remove `.navbar-collapse.collapse { display: none!important; }`

Comment: @thgaskell the menu items appear now. But automatically. I want it so that the menu items show up when the user clicks the menu icon. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Woops, forgot to mention you also should remove `class="visible-lg"` from the wrapper div.

Comment: @thgaskell thanks it worked! But do you know why the menu items stay out on screen sizes from like 770px to 1024px?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-9">
```

has a data-target targeting an id - the id should be applied on this line:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```